# Access one to many relationship data

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am learning to work with LINQ, EF etc. I have 2 auto generated edmx classes `course` and `student`. I have written a code to access the `course id` and `course name`. With the data I also want to fetch the data of the `students names` who have enrolled for the courses respectively. Following is my code.

```
testEntities1 t = new testEntities1();
                var u = (from g in t.courses
                         select new
                         {
                             g.C_Id,
                             g.C_Name,
                             dd = g.student.Select(r=>r.S_Name)

                         }).ToList();
```

Now how to use/get data from the property `dd` which i have selected which contains all the student names who have enrolled  for the course. I am able to put data to variable `u`. I just don't know how to proceed and get data out of `dd`. Please help. Following is the line for getting data of the `course id` and `course name`. How can I get the data of the student names.

```
List<course> ui = u.Select(d => new course() { C_Name = d.C_Name, C_Id = d.C_Id }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the Type of `Courses`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to fetch the data first into an `anonymous` type and then add it to your custom type `course`, you can do that directly as mentioned below. Now, since you have not mentioned the Type of `course`, I am considering following two possibilites:-

**Case 1:** If you have student names as `public List<string> Students_Enrolled { get; set; }` in `course` i.e. you want to fetch the list of students enrolled then:-

```
List<course> u = (from g in t.courses
                  select new course
                  {
                      C_ID = g.C_Id,
                      C_Name =  g.C_Name,
                      Students_Enrolled = g.student.Select(r => r.S_Name).ToList()
                  }).ToList();
```

**Case 2:** If you have student names as `public string Students_Enrolled { get; set; }` i.e. if you want to fetch comma separated student names then you can do this:-

```
List<course> u = (from g in t.courses
                  select new course
                  {
                      C_ID = g.C_Id,
                      C_Name =  g.C_Name,
                      Students_Enrolled = String.Join(",",g.student.Select(r => r.S_Name))
                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you see my course class it has ICollection<student>. I tried your first option, but i am getting error as cannot convert from List<string> to List<student>

Comment: @user2998990 - Because if you notice I have mentioned in Case 1, I have considered Students_Enrolled to be `List<string>` that is the reason I asked you for type of `course`.

Comment: but now what can be done.? I have an auto generated class of cousrse which has ICollection<student>

Comment: @user2998990 - The problem is with your class signature itself. See, in vaiable `u` you are fetching `S_Name` in `dd` but how can names be mapped to `ICollection<student>`? Either you need to store them in a separate property or fetch the complete `student` object. Which way you prefer?

Comment: when I fetch complete object then I get a self referencing problem. Please refer this Link(new question i posted today)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393238/self-referencing-issue-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment43234168_27393238

Comment: @user2998990 - Hmm..I saw that, but in this case you need to pick either of two.